# Efficently find divisors of numbers up to 20 digits

Tags: divisors-algebraic-geometry

I am aware that finding divisors of large numbers is a well known mathematical problem (which is one of the reasons why cryptography works).
Most solutions I've stumbled across used prime factorization to speed up the process a bit. However, on numbers bigger then $2^{32}$ all these solutions started to take seconds, minutes and hours.

For some reason [this website](http://www.javascripter.net/math/calculators/divisorscalculator.htm) can find the divisors for numbers up to $20$,  digits, thats around $2^{64}$, within milliseconds.
The algorithm can be seen by looking at the page source code. Apparently the input number is splitted into a high and a low section. Can somebody tell me the algorithm used here, and why it is so fast?

Comment: For numbers of this size, I think the most widely used is SQUFOF and its variations.

Answer (score 1):

*Mathematica* factors 20-digit integers in 0.000225 seconds:

```
Timing[FactorInteger[54605705157543059870]]

{0.000225, 
   {{2, 1}, {5, 1}, {7, 1}, {193, 1}, {811, 1}, {4983813894767, 1}}}
```

and its speed is due, apparently, to its use of trial division, Pollard p−1, Pollard rho, elliptic curve, and quadratic sieve algorithms. [Elliptic Curve Method](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11286/does-mathematica-use-the-elliptic-curve-method-ecm-in-factorinteger).

Comment: That might be true, but how can they achieve such speeds? What algorithm is used?

Comment: According to this (https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11286/does-mathematica-use-the-elliptic-curve-method-ecm-in-factorinteger) *Mathematica* uses the Elliptic Curve Method (ECM).

Answer (score 0):

The [code here](http://www.javascripter.net/math/primes/factorization.htm) uses a brute force search, with the slight optimization of sieving $\bmod 30$.